# Can not restore SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have trouble to restore SQL Server 2008 database. I receive an error message when I try to restore that restore failed and database is already in use. I try to restore backup from my D drive. 
Why I receive this error?

Comment: Please add more details. A screenshot about the error message would be nice start.

Comment: @vonPryz No, a screenshot would _not_ be a nice start, but copy/paste of the error message text would. Screenshots are bad because they are not searcheable.

Comment: @mustaccio Please see the original question why a screenshot was asked for.  As a side note, quite a few Windows' dialogs actually support `ctrl+c` for copying the text content.

Answer (score 2):

Likely your database (the one your are attempting to restore/replace) currently has open connections.

Try this logic:

```
ALTER DATABASE <yourdatabase> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE <yourdatabase> FROM DISK = "D:\Backups\BackupFile.Bak" WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY;

ALTER DATABASE <yourdatabase> SET MULTI_USER;
```

Setting the database to single user mode will close/rollback any existing connections except the current session

Set it back to multi user afterwards to return it to normal.

Comment: On what assumption you base this guess? Maybe user is out of disk space, lacks permissions, has syntax error in command (this is unlikely, more like wrong GUI settings I'd say), is trying to restore log instead of database and so on.

Comment: On the basis user states error as being 'database already in use'. Suggests connections open, which is a common restore failure. My answer states the likely issue with a potential solution based on the information provided.